# Issue with Git commits and reverting back

Tags: git, github

I was merging the `master` branch into a sub branch so that I could get the latest updated code into that sub branch.

After merging I realized I missed something so I wanted to undo the merge.

I am using [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/) and didn't have internet at the time to look up how to undo the merge correctly. So I stupidly committed the merge hoping I could just revert back to a previous commit which I did. All seemed ok.

But then when I tried merging the `master` back into the sub branch, it didn't pick up all the conflicts and changes like it had when I first did the merge. I think this is because I have the history of the old merge there.

Once I got my Internet connection back, I search and I tried running the following command to revert back to the commit prior to the original merge:

```
git reset --hard HASH
```

This seemed to work. I then tried merging the `master` branch again but it still doesn't pick up the conflicts and changes. And it is still showing up the commits I thought would have been deleted when I ran the above command.

How do I permanently delete everything after the commit I did before the first merge? Am I missing something?

Thanks so much for your help in advance.

Comment: What does `git log` show for the branch?

Comment: If merging `master` into your branch is showing the commits, after you reset branch, it sounds like you merged it into master before resetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved it was the following... Maybe it was a ltitle more complicated because I use GitHub for Mac...

I reset the the last commit hash that I wanted:

```
git reset --hard <identified-commit-hash>
```

I then created a sub-branch from the sub-branch I was having issues with. This is what stopped any history coming back when I merged `master` into it again.

As I said this might be because of GitHub for Mac not working correctly but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your branch was cut from master then it might be better to rebase the branch.  http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing.

```
git checkout sub-branch
git rebase master
```

If the conflict on your sub branch is due to an earlier merge from master and you want to undo that then you would want to revert.

```
git revert SHA-1
```

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like this, using `reset` in conjunction with `reflog` may yield better results as to where the last-good-commit was left. This will re-write your working directory and commit history to a desired point.

This will require using the command line.

1. Review what changes have been made (moves of `HEAD`)

   `git reflog`
2. Identify in the `reflog` which hash represents the last-good commit

   The commit hash or the `HEAD@{ }` value are both usable
3. Reset the current branch's HEAD to specified hash, rewrite working directory

   `git reset --hard <identified-commit-hash>`